# Cuda Out of Memory Error after few successful batches

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Here is my code. I am receiving CUDA out of memory error after executing 140 batches successfully. 
I have used item method to avoid storing tensor. Used empty_cache, gc collect, retain_graph as False while calling backward. But all in vain. Kindly suggest.

```
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs+1):
    train_loss = 0.0
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (image,label) in enumerate(loaders['train']):
    # move to GPU
    if use_cuda:
        image,label = image.cuda(), label.cuda()
    if (batch_idx +1) % 20 == 0:
        print('Batch Id '+ str(batch_idx +1))
    ## find the loss and update the model parameters accordingly
    ## record the average training loss, using something like
    ## train_loss = train_loss + ((1 / (batch_idx + 1)) * (loss.data - 
    ## train_loss))
    optimizer_scratch.zero_grad()
    output = model_scratch(image)
    loss = criterion_scratch(output,label)
    ##loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
    loss.backward()

    optimizer_scratch.step()
    train_loss = train_loss + ((1 / (batch_idx + 1)) * (loss.item() - 
    train_loss))
    torch.cuda.empty_cache() 
    ##gc.collect()
```

Comment: are you using `train_loss` to track the progress of your training? if you remove it completely, do you still run out of memory?

Comment: Hi, I was actually using valid_loss to keep track of my training at the end of each epoch...But I have not copied that code here since it is throwing error even without the valid_loss code... As you suggested I removed the train loss completely. But it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: In case PyTorch isn't releasing GPU memory, try manually deleting the CUDA variables using `.delete()` on them at the end of each epoch.

Comment: @Kaus, Just wondering how you resolved this error. I am facing the same issue.